# FlurryAgent.logError is not working in Sencha app

Tags: sencha-touch, flurry, hybrid-mobile-app

I am using flurry in my sencha app for iphone  and i added flurry.js file in index.html with following  snippet

```
<script src=”https://cdn.flurry.com/js/flurry.js”></script>
```

When i try to track application error with FlurryAgent.logError it gives me error on this line.

Error :

1.SyntaxError: Invalid character '\u0894'

2.Error: The following classes are not declared even if their files have been loaded: 'SampleApp.controller.tablet.HomeController'. Please check the source code of their corresponding files for possible typos: 'app/controller/tablet/HomeController.js

While i am using FlurryAgent.startSession and it is working for me .

According to me there is logError event related file is missing but in flurry documentation, it  mentioned to include only  flurry.js file .

If any one out of there help me to solve this problem it would be great. I am waiting for reply .

Thanks,

Bharti sharma

Comment: The error you have as #2 wouldn't get called because of `logError()`. You likely have something wrong with your HomeController.js file. Can you post it?

Comment: I agree with jprofitt here. #2 error is probably because you have incorrect view name on your HomeController. Carefully check the whole class name and any associated requires.

Comment: This error is coming when i add "FlurryAgent.logError(response.status, response.statusText, 0);" line in my HomeController.js file . If i remove it then did't get any error.

Answer (score 0):

You probably copied the commands out of the PDF document. The PDF has some invalid characters that will cause syntax errors in javascript.

I fixed a similar issue by deleting all of the . ( ) ; , characters with ones I typed myself. Fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The snippet has typographical quotation marks (”) instead of normal ones ("). Typical error when copy and pasting from styled sources.